# Customize the command shell default prompt

Tags: bash

Need help to change the command prompt. I want short name. Look below :

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ cd workspace
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/workspace$ cd Ruby
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/workspace/Ruby$
```

I am looking for my initial command prompt, when I will open it using 'Ctrl+Alt+t' as

```
 $(arup):
 $(arup): cd workspace
 $(workspace): cd Ruby
 $(Ruby) :
```

In my `~/.bashrc` file  did put as below :

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1
PS1='\w\ $ '
else
PS1='\w\ $ '
```

By replacing

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    # PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    PS1='arup :\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

But I didn't find any change in my shell:

[image]
May I have some help to configure the above settings ?

Comment: are you updating the bashrc source with " source ~/.bashrc "? (no quotes)

Comment: @MuffinStateWide I open `~/.bashrc` using Gedit, then put the content and saved it. That's what I did and tried. But no result.

Comment: @MuffinStateWide It is not permanent, every time I need to source it. `kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ source ~/.bashrc
~\ $ cd workspace
~/workspace\ $ cd Ruby
~/workspace/Ruby\ $` But this is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took help from [**How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

I did first `sudo gedit /etc/bashrc`. Then did below change :

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
PS1='(arup~>\W)$'
```

Now my prompt is coming close to my expectation -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can create an alias for `cd ~/workspace/Ruby` as `chg_dir`

Comment: I want it to be happened dynamically... See my post description..

Comment: sorry I got it wrong, I edited my answer. Is this something you are looking for ?

Comment: No.. I am looking for `$(arup):` to come when I open the terminal,then each time I will change the CWD, it should come as `$(CWD_name)`..

Comment: I would advice you NOT to change root prompt name. It always shows as `username@hostname` so that when someone connect to other machine with ssh it changes to `remote-username@remote-hostname`. However, you can force terminal to always show present-working-directory(PWD/CWD) instead of full directory path like in [this image](http://i.imgur.com/vQUWlyp.png).

Answer (score 0):

In  `~/.bashrc`, search for section:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Remove the `@\h`, and replace the `\w` with an uppercase `\W`, so that it becomes:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W\$ '
fi
```

check [this](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html) for more info

Comment: I tried, but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

in .bash_profile, enter

```
set color_prompt = yes
```

this applies to root user on 17.04 onwards, and to all users on 16.04

then in relevant .bashrc or /root/bashrc, update the color_prompt section as below.

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\ [\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W\$ '
fi
```